# How can I discard pending DocumentReference writes when offline?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase Firestore documents to publish the location of my users on a map, so they see each other. This works fine when all of them have good connectivity, but sometimes their mobiles can't connect to the Firebase servers and it seems that the writes are cached: whenever they recover connectivity all the pending location writes are sent in bulk.

The effect for other users is that they see the position of a person stop, and after a while they start moving really quick until the map position catches the real value. This is annoying and a waste of bandwidth.

I have tried disabling the persistence cache but this doesn't help (it would only help if the transmisor app would die, but as long as it lives the positions are cached in memory).

Maybe the problem is that I shouldn't be using documents for this purpose and there is another Firebase mechanism which allows *discarding* stale write data for the purposes of real time communication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All write operations that are performed while the device is offline are queued until the connection with the Firebase servers is reestablished. Unfortunately, there is no API that can help you control which write operation are queued and which are not.

The simplest solution I can think of is to use [Firestore transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), which are currently not persisted to disk and thus will be lost when the application is offline.

So, transactions are not supported for offline use, they can't be cached or saved for later. This is because a transaction absolutely requires round trip communications with server in order to ensure that the code inside the transaction completes successfully. So you can use transaction only while online because the transactions are network dependent.

Comment: Still no API that can tell which write operations are queued?

Comment: @RamiAlloush No, not yet.

Comment: @TahaSami No, not yet.

Comment: @AlexMamo Check my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75307153/preventing-pending-writes-in-firebase-with-transactions-not-working), please

Comment: @TahaSami I just answered it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this by **only making requests if you can connect to firestore.** Here's a helper function that will determine if you're connected or not. It's similar to using a transaction since both methods involve making a read request.

If you don't plan on invoking the function that much, the read costs will probably be negligible. However, to save the cost of reads, you could also consider pinging some server or a cloud function instead of firestore itself. Doing so might be a less accurate way of testing connection to firestore though.

```
import {
    doc,
    getDocFromServer,
} from "firebase/firestore"

async function canConnectToFirestore(){

     //navigator.onLine can only say for certain if you're disconnected
     //For more info on navigator.onLine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine
     if (!navigator.onLine) 
         return false

     //db is initialized from getFirestore()
     try{
         await getDocFromServer(doc(db, "IrrelevantText","IrrelevantText"))
         return true
     }
     catch(e){
         return false
     }
}


async function example(){
     if(await canConnectToFirestore()) console.log("Do something with firestore")
}
```