# How can I add a document to a Firebase collection inside a transaction?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can add an object to a Firebase collection using the `CollectionReference.add()` method, then calling `addOnSuccessListener()` on the returned object to fetch the actual values stored in Firebase. However, [I want to run this inside a transaction block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308344/how-can-i-discard-pending-documentreference-writes-when-offline) to avoid caching of the writes, which otherwise don't fail when the client is offline.

But `Transaction` objects only have `.get`, `.delete`, `.set` and `.update` methods. How do I add a value to collection inside the transaction?

Comment: set, works as add if no document is found

Comment: .set does NOT allow for addOnSuccessListener, and does NOT allow for the return of the document ID (i.e. it does not return a DocumentSnapshot).  I have a transaction that wants the Id of the created document for subsequent parts of the transaction, but it seems transaction doesn't allow for it (likely for the reasons above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the documentation :

[image]
[image]

Therefore, you can call set in your transaction to create any new documentations if they aren't found. Hope this helps

Comment: How can you use the `set()` method to get an auto-generated document ID?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `set()` method as he said, ill give you an example:

```
transaction.set(CollectionReference.doc(), {
                attribute1: ...,
                ...
                attributen: ...});
```

with `CollectionReference.doc()` you are creating the new doc with the values given in the object