# Handling requests with bad internet connection in flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out a way to handle write requests on timeout but the problem I'm facing is that when I make a request with a bad internet connection and it triggers the timeout. The moment I get a stable internet connection, the request would be sent because it is saved in the cache that firebase use for offline support. **is there any way to delete that specific request from the queue, or a way to handle the failed request?**

here is the code am using

```dart
void add_service_history(
      {required String product_name,
      required int cost,
      required DateTime dateTime,
      required BuildContext context,
      required int quantity}) async {
      //the write request
      await collectionReference_history
          .add({
            "product_name": product_name,
            "cost": cost,
            "date": dateTime,
            "quantity": quantity
          })
          .then((value) {
            //successful write 
            id = value.id;
            notifyListeners();
            return Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "Added",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                textColor: Colors.green,
                fontSize: 20.0);
          })
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5))
          .onError((error, stackTrace) {
            //failed write
            return Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "FAILED check your internet conenction",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                textColor: Colors.red,
                fontSize: 20.0);

          });

  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I discard pending DocumentReference writes when offline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308344/how-can-i-discard-pending-documentreference-writes-when-offline)

Comment: Am trying to figure out a way to do this in flutter but there isn't a clear way yet , thank you for the respond it helped me a bit with searching .

Comment: I kind of solved the problem by making a read request on a document before every write request with a 3 second timeout , this is not an optimized solution by any means, but in my case it's okay because the number of writes per day won't pass 2000 in the most extreme case .

Comment: You can use try catch block on TimeoutException and remove failed requests from cache using `await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();` take a look at [this snippet](https://codefile.io/f/DE8ulCttNw6HhlPe9qKq).

Comment: I tried this code and ended with this error :
**E/flutter (22590): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.**

Comment: @DZUYScuti then the best approach is to use transactions just like @tomerpacific suggested above as transactions require active internet connection and needs round trip confirmation which is what your are looking for. Although using `clearPersistence()` should also work if you index frequently accessed queries in the firebase console. As that is what error is suggesting.